# Is there a built-in way to do an Intersect on a List of Lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have

```
{ { "a", "b", "c" }, { "d", "b", "c" }, { "z", "a", "c" } }
```

I can loop through the outer list and do an intersect on each inner list and get:

```
{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "z" }
```

However, I'm wondering if there's something built into .NET to do this. I feel like there should be a way to do something like:

```
listOfLists.Intersect();
```

Normally, you'd put another list in there to intersect two lists, but it seems like there should be a way to do it within LINQ.

I did end up doing an overload of it for my own purposes, but I'm wondering if I didn't need to.

```
    internal static string Intersect(this IEnumerable<string> inputs)
    {
        var temp = inputs.FirstOrDefault().ToCharArray();
        foreach (var item in inputs.Skip(1))
        {
            temp = temp.Intersect(item).ToArray();
        }
        return new string(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Your sample is wrong - you should only be getting `c` if you're doing an intersection.  Did you mean union instead?  What are trying to find here, common letters, unique letters?  Note this will only reliably work with ASCII text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0) LINQ operator.

```
internal static string Intersect(this IEnumerable<string> inputs) =>
    string.Join("", inputs.Select(x => x.AsEnumerable()).Aggregate((x, y) => x.Union(y)));
```

Note that the expected result you showed is a `Union` of all the letters in the three strings, rather than an `Intersect`. But if you actually meant an intersect, just use `x.Intersect(y)`.

Comment: Will it give better performance than .SelectMany(l => l, (list,item) => item).Distinct()?

Comment: Yeah, when I initially wrote the question, I asked about intersect union except and concat. I cleaned it up to just one for the purposes of clarity, but did not leave the correct example. Thanks.